# In the pom.xml file of my Spring Boot Maven project, I am encountering the following error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, maven-plugin

getting below error while attempting to build the JAR

```
Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources {execution: default-resources} (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources {execution: default-resources}
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeMojo(MavenExecutionContext.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.lambda$0(MavenExecutionContext.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.lambda$2(MavenBuilderImpl.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeMojo(MavenExecutionContext.java:338)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:300)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:514)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:416)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:205)
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1856)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1804)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:114)
    ... 36 more
```

Although my Spring Boot Maven application runs successfully, I am encountering an error in the pom.xml file. Additionally, the same error persists when attempting to build the JAR.

Comment: it is m2e installed in your clips editor ???

Comment: There are microservices projects, where all services except one are successfully starting up.

Comment: do you try to make build or rebuild  maven project .

Comment: its works by removing
**<filtering>true</filtering>** tag in *pox.xml* file

Comment: ok , very good , we learn nothing new . nice , thank you